# Kubuntu Plasma widgets keep resizing!

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 20.04, kde, widgets

**So I have a few widgets on my Kubuntu desktop, sized to align with a nsfw wallpaper (changed in the images I've provided).**

[image]

**My problem is that after each reboot, the 2 widgets at the top, namely calendar and resources monitor keep resizing on their own. This also happens sometimes when I log out and log back in.**

[image]

I have had this problem since I've added the widgets. Currently on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, proprietary drivers from Nvidia, running the compton compositor (problem was present even with the default/kde compositor).

Any help in solving this issue is greatly appreciated :)

P.S.: I am not the most proficient linux user ever :(

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I kinda solved the issue by adding the widgets to a panel. However, now i need to find out how to resize widgets inside panels...

Oh well, at least it's progress :)

Edit: Turns out Plasma is not very good with Nvidia (or is it the other way around?). Reverting back to Nouveau drivers solved a lot of the crashes and graphical bugs I've been having. As far as the widgets resizing themselves, I still haven't found a way to fix them and ended up not using the widgets affected by this issue.

I will leave the question unsolved, if someone find a way to fix this.

Comment: Also, this is just a workaround for the issue. If someone more knowledgeable than me could shed some light it would be really great.