# How do you move icons on Plasma desktop with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, icons, plasma

Running Kubuntu 20.04.

Is there a way to move desktop icons using only the keyboard???

I have quite a few widgets on my desktop (Plasmataker included :) and when i add a new icon on the desktop, sometimes it ends up underneath a widget. Placing the widgets inside a panel is not an option, for me at least, as some of the widgets on my desktop don't size very well within a panel (see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261407/kubuntu-plasma-widgets-keep-resizing)).